# Terniary operator not working in dictionary for loop

Tags: python, if-statement, conditional-statements, operation

I'm creating a dictionary to find all the unique values in a certain column of a file and counting how many times they appear.

The following code works:

```
content_ratings = {}

for app in apps_data[1:]:
    c_rating = app[10]

    if c_rating in content_ratings:
        content_ratings[c_rating] += 1
    else:
        content_ratings[c_rating] = 1
```

This works fine. However. I'm trying to do it using a terniary operator.

```
for app in apps_data[1:]:
    c_rating = app[10]

    content_ratings[c_rating] += 1 if c_rating in content_ratings else content_ratings[c_rating] = 1
```

Where is the error in my code?

Answer (score 1):

Assignment are *statements*, not expressions, and as such cannot appear in a conditional expression. Your attempt is parsed as

```
content_ratings[c_rating] += (1 if c_rating in content_ratings
  else content_ratings[c_rating]) = 1
```

That is, the conditional expression selects one of two values, not one of two statements, with the result being an invalid l-value for the first of the two chained assignments.

Instead, use the `setdefault` method:

```
content_ratings.setdefault(c_rating, 0) += 1
```

or use a `defaultdict`:

```
import collections


content_ratings = collections.defaultdict(int)

for app in apps_data[1:]:
    c_rating = app[10]
    content_ratings[c_rating] += 1
```

Answer (score 0):

How about that?

```
for app in apps_data[1:]:
    c_rating = app[10]

    content_ratings[c_rating] = content_ratings[c_rating] + 1 if c_rating in content_ratings else content_ratings[c_rating]
```